# Can I switch between python 32 bit and python 64 bit during the execution of a program?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pywinauto

**Requirement:**

Uninstall Application from Add remove programs. The code for this requires python 64 bit. My python script from which I want to perform uninstall operation requires python 32 bit as there are DLLs that are compiled using 32 bit python.

Is there anyway I can accomplish this? Is there a possibility to switch between the two architectures of python? I was wondering I can keep the the uninstall script as a separate python module and somehow force it to run using python 64 bit. Possible?

Python experts please help.

Python version : 2.7.12

**Structure:**

```
My python application (require 32 bit python)

    Uninstall() (require 64 bit python)

My script continues (require 32 bit python)
```

**Code for Uninstall()**

```
import pywinauto

pywinauto.Application().Start(r'explorer.exe')
explorer = pywinauto.Application().Connect(path='explorer.exe')

# Go to "Control Panel -> Programs and Features"
NewWindow = explorer.Window_(top_level_only=True, active_only=True,     class_name='CabinetWClass')
try:
    print "hello"
    NewWindow.AddressBandRoot.ClickInput()
    NewWindow.TypeKeys(r'Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features{ENTER}', with_spaces=True, set_foreground=False)
    ProgramsAndFeatures = explorer.Window_(top_level_only=True, active_only=True, title='Programs and Features', class_name='CabinetWClass')

    # Wait while list of programs is loading
    explorer.WaitCPUUsageLower(threshold=5)

    item_7z = ProgramsAndFeatures.FolderView.GetItem('7-Zip 9.20 (x64 edition)')
    item_7z.EnsureVisible()
    item_7z.ClickInput(button='right', where='icon')
    explorer.PopupMenu.MenuItem('Uninstall').Click()

    Confirmation = explorer.Window_(title='Programs and Features', class_name='#32770', active_only=True)
    if Confirmation.Exists():
        Confirmation.Yes.ClickInput()
        Confirmation.WaitNot('visible')

    WindowsInstaller = explorer.Window_(title='Windows Installer', class_name='#32770', active_only=True)
    if WindowsInstaller.Exists():
        WindowsInstaller.WaitNot('visible', timeout=20)

    SevenZipInstaller = explorer.Window_(title='7-Zip 9.20 (x64 edition)', class_name='#32770', active_only=True)
    if SevenZipInstaller.Exists():
        SevenZipInstaller.WaitNot('visible', timeout=20)

    if '7-Zip 9.20 (x64 edition)' not in     ProgramsAndFeatures.FolderView.Texts():
        print "OK"
finally:
    NewWindow.Close()
```

Comment: It’s easier to use backend=“uia”, when creating Application object. It doesn’t require different Python interpreters for 32-bit and 64-bit app. But the hierarchy will have different structure and you may have to rewrite the script.

Comment: Hi @Vasily, I tried that but it didn't help. With 32 bit python installed on the system the above code throws the error but It works perfectly fine if 64 bit python is installed:

Comment: C:\Users\labuser\Desktop>uninstall.py
hello
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\labuser\Desktop\uninstall.py", line 40, in <module>  NewWindow.close() File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 368,in __getattribute__  ctrls = self.__resolve_control(self.criteria)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pywinauto\application.py", line 249, in __resolve_control
    raise e.original_exception
pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError: {'active_only': True, 'class_name': 'CabinetWClass', 'process': 7124, 'top_level_only': True, 'backend': u'uia'}   .

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using 2 different processes?

1. Launch a 32-bit python process for you application.
2. Your applications requests execution of a separate 64-bit python process to run your `Uninstall` function.
3. Your application waits until the 64-bit python process terminates.
4. Your application continues running.

Comment: Thanks. Seems that can work but can you please elaborate a little how can that be done? How to launch 32 bit and 64 bit python process? By process I assume you mean threads? Sorry for the noob questions. Python is new to me. It would be really helpful if you could write down some lines of code for accomplishing the above. Thanks in advance!